# Mysql - Order by two columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

> **events**: id, name, date_from, date_to
>
> **event_recurrences**: id, event_id, date_from, date_to

**event records:**

```
1, 'test 1', '2011-03-03 23:00:00', NULL
2, 'test 2', '2011-03-05 23:00:00', NULL
3, 'test 3', '2011-03-12 23:00:00', NULL
```

**event recurrences records:**

```
1, 1, 2011-03-10 23:00:00, NULL
2, 1, 2011-03-17 23:00:00, NULL
3, 1, 2011-03-24 23:00:00, NULL
```

Now I'd like to get all event and get the sorting right which is my problem right now.

my approach:

```
SELECT e.*, r.*
FROM events AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_recurrences AS r ON (e.id = r.event_id)
ORDER BY r.date_from, e.date_from
```

The problem is now that the records are not ordered correctly. 
Records without recurrences are always sorted before ones with.

Could you help to get the dates ordered ascending without prioritising records without recurrences.

Comment: You need to tell us what "correctly" means (no, we can't read your mind, and no, it's not obvious - are you trying to somehow sort by date?). So far, we only know that it should be *something else* than what you have.

Comment: `left inner join` is not legal. Is the real query `left outer join` ?

Comment: "Correctly" would be different from the sentence before (common sense). But i'll rephrase it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax to put NULLs at the bottom:

```
ORDER BY IF (ISNULL(my_field), 1, 0), my_field;
```

Other database systems have something like NULLS LAST/NULLS FIRST

Comment: thanks you so much! That did the trick: ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(r.date_from), e.date_from, r.date_from) ASC

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
ORDER BY least(r.date_from, e.date_from)
```

or

```
ORDER BY greatest(r.date_from, e.date_from)
```

I don't know if that's exactly what you need, but it will give you an idea...

Answer (score 0):

problem is you joined events and then reoccurred them, if they dont have reoccurrences, the events that dont reoccur will not be ordered first, due to the fact that you have said to sort by the reoccurred event first, which if it didnt would be NULL, NULL is less than everything.

Only way I could see you getting the answer you wanted would be:

```
select * from e union 
select (r.event_id as id, e.event, t.date_from from r 
   left join e on r.event_id=e.id) 
order by date_from
```

which should join the tables into one long list and sort by date

Comment: is there no way to override the null fields with the value of e.date_from?